# overwrite a dataframe inside a dictionary of dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

**Goal**

I'm trying to create a main DataFrame. From this main DataFrame, utilize the "name" column to provide each value in "name" with a DataFrame that is a copy of the main DataFrame. As the "name" column grows, the number of DataFrames will grow.
This is done by utilizing a dictionary of DataFrames, so that I can reference each persons DataFrame easily.

Afterwards, I apply filters to each person's respective DataFrame.

**Issues I am facing**

1. The code gives a "name" error, in reference to the column called "name". This issue occurs in the last row of code.

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import copy

df = {'name': ['bob', 'alex', 'ryan', 'andrew', 'goliath'], 'right_arm_length': [1, 2, 3, 8, 7], 'left_arm_length': [3, 4, 2, 5, 8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df) #Create main dataframe

dictionary_df={}  #Create empty dictionary to store dataframes in

 
for index, value in df['name'].items():
    dictionary_df[value + '_df'] = copy.deepcopy(df)        #This will create a dataframe for each person                        
    for idx in range(len(df)):          #Filtration process begins here   
        if idx != index:                #Prevent from comparing person to themselves
            dictionary_df[value + '_df'] =  dictionary_df[value + '_df'][dictionary_df[value + '_df']['name'] == value]['right_arm_length'] < dictionary_df[value + '_df']['left_arm_length'][idx]          ####**Issue is here**
```

Note: The last row is used to update `dictionary_df[value + '_df']` after applying a condition where the owner of the DataFrame's `right_arm_length` is smaller than all other person's `left_arm_length`. So for `bob_df`, it would compare `bob`'s `right_arm_length` to the `left_arm_length` of all other people in `bob_df`.

Comment: It appears the issue is that dictionary_df[value + '_df'] no longer contains the variable "name". If I were to replace dictionary_df[value + '_df'] with "x" in the last line of code on the left side of the equal sign, the code works. Will look into fixing this, unless someone comes up with a solution.

Comment: could you explain in words what you want to accomplish in the last row?

Comment: The last row is used to update dictionary_df[value + '_df'] after applying a condition where the owner of the dataframe's right_arm_length is smaller than all other persons left_arm_length. So for bob_df, it would compare bob's right_arm_length  to the left_arm_length of all other persons in bob_df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a boolean mask and iteratively filter `df`:

```
out = {}
for name in df['name']:
    msk = df['name']==name
    out[f'{name}_df'] = df[(df.loc[msk, 'right_arm_length'].iat[0] < df['left_arm_length']) | msk]
```

Output:

```
{'bob_df':       name  right_arm_length  left_arm_length
 0      bob                 1                3
 1     alex                 2                4
 2     ryan                 3                2
 3   andrew                 8                5
 4  goliath                 7                8,
 'alex_df':       name  right_arm_length  left_arm_length
 0      bob                 1                3
 1     alex                 2                4
 3   andrew                 8                5
 4  goliath                 7                8,
 'ryan_df':       name  right_arm_length  left_arm_length
 1     alex                 2                4
 2     ryan                 3                2
 3   andrew                 8                5
 4  goliath                 7                8,
 'andrew_df':      name  right_arm_length  left_arm_length
 3  andrew                 8                5,
 'goliath_df':       name  right_arm_length  left_arm_length
 4  goliath                 7                8}
```

If you have Python >=3.8, you could use walrus operator and convert the above loop into a dict comprehension:

```
out = {f'{name}_df': df[(df.loc[(msk := df['name']==name), 'right_arm_length'].iat[0] < df['left_arm_length']) | msk] for name in df['name']}
```

Answer (score 1):

can you please check if this is what you want?

```
dictionary_df = {}
for index, value in df['name'].items():
  dictionary_df[value + '_df'] = copy.deepcopy(df)
  right_arm_length = dictionary_df[value + '_df'][dictionary_df[value + '_df']['name']==value]['right_arm_length'].iloc[0]
  dictionary_df[value + '_df'].loc[dictionary_df[value + '_df']['name']!=value] = dictionary_df[value + '_df'][dictionary_df[value + '_df']['left_arm_length'] > right_arm_length]
  dictionary_df[value + '_df'] = dictionary_df[value + '_df'].dropna()
```

Comment: This works well, however, there is 1 issue. In bob_df for instance, I don't want the condition in the last row of code to be applied to bob's data. In other words, in ryan_df, ryan should not be compared to ryan, and in alex_df, alex should not be compared to alex.
I attempted to do this with a condition that stated if the index it was iterating was equal to the index where name ="value", then don't apply the condition, but it wasn't working due to syntactical errors.
I want to do this so that if I have other conditions I want to apply, then for bob_df, bob's data will still be there to use.

Comment: Can you check the edited code?

Comment: That is an interesting approach, I like it. It looks like the 5th line here selects the rows that don't contain name = "value". This leaves the dataset with rows that passed the condition and don't contain name = "value", and replaces the rows that didn't pass the condition with NaNs. In the final line of code, you have the dataframe drop NaNs so that way only the rows that passed the condition and contain name = "value" are left. Brilliant, thanks so much. It's nice that it is under 1 for loop as well, makes things process quicker.